# submenus not expanding some times

Tags: theming, 8, navigation

As the title suggests.

We have a menu with several top level items and then sub-menus under each element.

All the children for a given parent should expand when the parent is selected.

It works... most of the time then some times it does not... I can see no pattern to it. Clearing the site cache usually fixes it for a period but then the problem will return. Sometimes it will take days to reoccur other times it will take 5 min.

I cannot see any errors in the php error log file and no javascript errors being reported by the browser. Users on my network and elsewhere seem to be affected.

Can anyone give guidance as to what may be producing such an error? Is this a common error?

A 'sometimes' working menu is not really acceptable but locking it open is sub-optimal also as there are lots of children.